# Combine two linestrings in different rows using PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, gps, openstreetmap, postgis

Let me give an example to explain the problem. I have a OSM file for a portion of a city, say Santa Clara, CA, USA which I loaded into Postgres+PostGIS. I am trying to create a database of all roads in the OSM file along with their GPS coordinates. Let us consider an example road called 'Central Expressway'. My query was

```
SELECT NAME, OSM_ID, AS_TEXT(ST_TRANSFORM(WAY, 4326)) AS whole_road FROM planet_osm_roads WHERE NAME = 'CENTRAL EXPRESSWAY'
```

However this gives me different rows which correspond to different way segments of the same road (Central Expressway) with the GPS coordinates being stored as a linestring for each row. For example if obtain something like

```
Central Expressway |  id_1 | LINESTRING(x_1 y_1, x_2 y_2, x_3 y_3)


Central Expressway |  id_2 | LINESTRING(x_4 y_4, x_5 y_5)
```

I understand that is how the data was stored in the OSM file. My question is how do I concatenate the different linestrings into a single one, i.e. something like

```
Central Expressway |  id_new | LINESTRING(x_1 y_1, x_2 y_2, x_3 y_3, x_4 y_4, x_5 y_5)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show us sample output?

Comment: Please put this into your question as formatted code and also show us how you want it to look.

Comment: Something like this  Central Expressway |  25866275 | LINESTRING(-121.965531312154 37.3742859788242,-121.964465371237 37.3741961013297)
 Central Expressway | 377448096 | LINESTRING(-121.95097034005 37.3744384633502,-121.951616318571 37.3744541686677). Note the field osm_id is also displayed in between the name and linestring. Each way or segment does have a unique osm_id so can I make use of it to concatenate? Thanks

Comment: Sorry for that. I have re-formatted the question as per your suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In OSM, as in virtually all GIS systems, long roads are stored as multiple `linestrings` for topological reasons. If you want to get all coordinates of a single road, then you should first concatenate the geometries and only then convert to a `WKT` format:

```
SELECT name, As_Text(
               ST_LineMerge(
                 ST_Collect(
                   ST_Transform(way, 4326)
                 )
               )
             ) AS whole_road
FROM planet_osm_roads
WHERE name = 'CENTRAL EXPRESSWAY'
GROUP BY name;
```

`ST_Collect()` will group all linestrings that compose Central Expressway into a single `multilinestring` and `ST_LineMerge()` will then convert that to a single `linestring` in a topologically sensible way (i.e. ordered from one end point to the next starting point).

Comment: Thanks much Patrick. I had to add an extra `GROUP BY name` and the query almost works. However the `ST_LineMerge()` still doesn't convert the `multilinestring` to a `linestring`. I guess that depends on the shape of the road, right? I checked and some of the linestrings do not share a common point (i.e. are disjoint) in the OSM file that I have

Comment: If linestrings are disjoint then there is nothing you can do to automatically merge them into 1 linestring, short of writing a custom function that forces linestrings to join if they are close together. Added the `GROUP BY` clause to the answer.